# R: How do I cross-reference data.frames for discrepancies?

Tags: r, database, function, dataframe, rstudio

**BACKGROUND:**
I have two data frames that two researchers have used to manually input time data that tracks how a group of participants reach a consensus in making a decision. We are doing this by logging the time of each preference
statement as well as the preference (ranked by priority).

**QUESTION:**
My question is, what functions or packages can I use to show me the discrepancies in the two data tables.

**EXAMPLE:**

> discrepancies <- show_discrepancies(myData1, myData2)
>
> discrepancies

***outputExample1***

provides a data frame containing only the entries that do not match

***outputExample2***

provides a combined data frame, with entries from both myData1 and myData2, and the entries that do not have a match are highlighted red

either output would work but I would prefer ***outputExample1*** if possible

Comment: Questions asking for tool recommendations are off-topic here, so this will likely be closed. (However, look at the **daff** package; it's pretty slick.)

Comment: Questions just asking to recommend functions/packages are considered off topic. It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions (if packages/functions exist to help, they will be included in the answer)

Comment: Welcome to SO, Chris. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the help center article on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). As @MrFlick says, a good question will have sample input and desired output, rather than just text describing the behavior you're looking for.

Comment: This should be straightforward if you have one or more "key" variables that identify which observations from the first table should be paired with which observations from the second. First you'd join the two tables, to get a new combined table. Then you could filter to just show observations where the values differ.  https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/join.html

Comment: @JonSpring Thank you! I read the documentation and this is EXACTLY what I need. I will give it a shot at work today.

Comment: @JonSpring, Thank you again. the dplyr method was successful!

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the two data frames have the same structure, you can get **outputExample1** using the following function:

```
show_discrepancies <- function(data1, data2) {
  data <- rbind(data1, data2)
  data[!duplicated(data),]
}
```

Also take a look at the join functions available in the [dplyr package](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/).

Comment: Amazing! Thanks. Will give this a shot too and report back!!